# Is there an equivalent to this del.icio.us like Bookmarks plugin for NextCloud in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to store [tagged bookmarks](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/bookmarks) for my team in SharePoint Online.  It works similar to the old Web 2.0 site del.icio.us

Is there an equivalent to this in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, there is no similar Bookmark plugin in SharePoint.

However, you can refer to the following steps to enable the Bookmark function.

To enable the bookmark functionality, a SharePoint site admin need to activate the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature** on the site collection level and the **SharePoint Server Publishing feature** on the site level. After activating the two features, refer to the steps below to create a bookmark:

1.Create a page and input a section, for example, section1 in the page.

2.Edit the page and highlight the words section1.

3.Click Insert and then Link.

4.Click From Address.

5.Paste the URL of page1 in the Address box.

6.Type section1 in the Bookmark box.

7.Click Save.

Then you can use the link such as https://#section1 to access this bookmark.

Here is a video for your reference：

- **[Create "Bookmarks" or "Anchor links" in SharePoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-EcS3_FgcE)**